# how to simulate your app on real IOS devices

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6, xcode4.5

i have jailbreak iphone 4s with 6.1.2 (10B146) ios version. i hane maintain provisioning profile .the status of profile is valid.my device is add on member center it show there.but when i run the app using ios device a pop window open with
"***No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination***."
i m using Xcode Version 4.5.2 (4G2008a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Apps are not "simulated" on the device, they're run natively there.
2. Jailbreaking ain't magic. Xcode will still not permit you to just upload your app without the correct provisioning profiles and certificates and whatever (unless you binpatch Xcode itself or use some other kind of nasty hack, like the "iOSOpenDev" package).
3. So you have to actually copy your application bundle to your device (to the `/Applications` folder) and either restart SpringBoard or use the `uicache` utility to make it appear on the home screen.

Comment: i m not trying to upload my app.i just want to run on real device like i have iphone 4s. app run good on simulator but when i chose ios device to run then a pop up window with ""No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.""

Comment: @ranakhan Don't worry, I have prefectly understood your question. By "upload", I meant uploading to the device, not to the AppStore.

Comment: what should i do to run app on real device..should i restore my iphone to original software instead of jailbreak.

Comment: @ranakhan You should do what I described here. If you don't have a developer license, your device must be jailbroken. Try understanding my answer.